# Tomcat 6.0.20 @ STS 2.5.1==Error while app startup -No web.xml present

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

I am facing a problem while deploying my web app in STS 2.5.1 IDE. I am using Tomcat 6.As I am working in a development project, so rebuild and deployment of the project is very common.But sometimes while deploying my app , I receive **NO WEB.XML** present.

Although , I resolved this problem by removing app from tomcat, cleaned tomcat work directory, added app again, and start the server, then it worked.

My question - is this happening due to some cache being exhausted or there is some other cause.It seems that cleaning, removing and adding the prj work every time for me whenever this error is coming OR tomcat is not supposed to handle such a large project.It is very cumbersome procedure to remove, clean and restart again and again, after all you change your code a lot in development.

My technology stack is listed below:

SWF 2.3.0
Primefaces 2.2.1
JSF 2
Spring Security 3
Spring 3.1.0M1I
EhCache
Apache Tomcat 6.0
STS 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an eclipse issue.  It seems that eclipse is not able to clear its server cache directory. There are times that you'd have to manually clear this cache, especially in large projects where eclipse can't update some of the project's dependencies.

You'll find the projects deployed in your eclipse integrated tomcat server at:

> workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp\wtpwebapps